# How do I need to print vowels dataset from pandas series dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have generated a dataset using pandas series and need to print only set of details which contains vowels. ignore case it can be upper or lower

**My code :**

```
import pandas as pd
strname='AZCVFueioll'
df = pd.Series(list(strname)).value_counts().sort_values()
df
```

**Output :**

```
A    1
Z    1
a    1
C    1
V    1
F    1
u    1
e    1
i    1
o    1
l    2
```

**Expected output :** Need to print only the set of details which as vowels

```
a    2
c    1
u    1
e    1
i    1
o    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try convert with `lower` then `isin`

```
l =('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
out = df[df.index.str.lower().isin(l)]
Out[55]: 
i    1
A    1
u    1
e    1
o    1
dtype: int64
```

Update for the follow up question

```
l =('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
df.index = df.index.str.lower() 
out = df[df.index.isin(l)].groupby(level=0).sum()
out
Out[58]: 
a    1
e    1
i    1
o    1
u    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: How to do sum of 'A' and 'a'

Comment: @codeholic24 check the update

Comment: @codeholic24 convert the index to lower , then slice the data by checking whether the character in the list , then we can groupby then and sum all value with same index together

Comment: Any reference where i can lean pandas on high level

Comment: @codeholic24 you can check coursera ~